# LxD container on external drive not starting on another host

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive, container, lxc

I have identical OSes (Ubuntu 16.04) running on 2 hosts, with identical OS updates.

I also have identical LxD service installed (via `sudo apt-get install lxd`) and configured (via `sudo lxd init`) on both hosts.

Now, for both space-saving, portability/work-continuity reasons (because these 2 hosts are in different physical locations, behind their own firewalls that I don't control), *I thought, why not install all my LxD images and containers on an external drive that I could plug in one host or the other, interchangeably.*

For this, I installed my desired images and set up the desired containers on Host A, and copied the `/var/lib/lxd`, `/var/log/lxd`, and `/var/cache/lxd` folders (and their contents) to the external drive.

When I plugged the external drive into Host B, I could actually see my image- and (stopped) container-lists from Host A just fine. I could even launch new containers on Host B off of original, Host A images.

But when on Host B I tried to start a container, `foo`, originally started and stopped on Host A, I got the following error:

```
$ lxc start foo
error: Error calling 'lxd forkstart foo /var/lib/lxd/containers /var/log/lxd/foo/lxc.conf': err='exit status 1'
  lxc 20161217084040.956 ERROR lxc_start - start.c:lxc_spawn:1162 - failed to set up id mapping
  lxc 20161217084041.013 ERROR lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1354 - failed to spawn 'foo'
  lxc 20161217084041.564 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:run_buffer:347 - Script exited with status 1
  lxc 20161217084041.564 ERROR lxc_start - start.c:lxc_fini:555 - failed to run post-stop hooks for container 'foo'.
  lxc 20161217084041.566 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.566 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd//lxc/foo
  lxc 20161217084041.568 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.568 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/pids//lxc/foo
  lxc 20161217084041.569 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.569 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls//lxc/foo
  lxc 20161217084041.571 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.571 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb//lxc/foo
  lxc 20161217084041.573 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.573 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu//lxc/foo
  lxc 20161217084041.575 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.575 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer//lxc/foo
  lxc 20161217084041.576 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.576 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset//lxc/foo
  lxc 20161217084041.578 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.578 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio//lxc/foo
  lxc 20161217084041.580 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.580 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/devices//lxc/foo
  lxc 20161217084041.581 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.581 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/memory//lxc/foo
  lxc 20161217084041.583 ERROR lxc_conf - conf.c:userns_exec_1:4334 - Error setting up child mappings
  lxc 20161217084041.583 ERROR lxc_cgfsng - cgroups/cgfsng.c:recursive_destroy:983 - Error destroying /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event//lxc/foo

Try `lxc info --show-log foo` for more info
```

**Questions:**

Is some hardware-specific information of the host the container is originally launched on encoded in the on-disk serialized copy of the container (such as RAM, MAC address) making it impossible to start the container on another host with a slightly different hardware spec?

What else can I do for my use-case of portable containers via an external hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers for various login names in `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` on my 2 hosts were not matching, hence the runtime failure on starting the container on the host it was not originally created (or, launched) on.

Once I made these files on the 2 hosts identical, I was able to start the containers just fine.

*Note to LxD developers: A higher-level, more user-friendly error message from LxD, with hints to possible causes, would be a welcome addition to this GREAT piece of software!*